# What is the API rate limit for Google Hangouts API?

Tags: google-hangouts

What is the API rate limit for Google Hangouts API?

Comment: I'm sure you could have found these details after a little bit of searching.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation of those APIs you mention?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat

Answer (score 1):

To check the quotas and limits of the Hangouts Chat API you have to enable it for a project. As this quotas will be different depending on your subscription. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas and enter the project you have enabled the API for. There you can see read and write limits for the API.